# How does Apache load Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, apache

I was creating a simple Wordpress plugin which uses a javascript file. Although the PHP edits did not need a server refresh and were reflected immediately on page reload, the javascript edits were not reflected until I restarted the server (they did not work even on a hitting "Refresh" on xampp).

What I would like to know: 
1. How are Javascript files are loaded in Apache?
2. Is there anyway to configure it so that the files are loaded everytime I reload the page? ( I will be editing the Javascript files a lot. I do not want to be restarting the server everytime!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How are Javascript files are loaded in Apache?

**Ans:** It is the same with your html file or other static contents.

> Is there anyway to configure it so that the files are loaded everytime I reload the page?

**Ans:** This is not the problem of Apache, It is mostly because your browser caches your javascript file. Simply clear your browser caches.

Answer (score 1):

A nice trick you can do is to append a random string to the resource that you want to keep up to date every pageload. Ex.:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/myScript.js?p=<?php print sha1(time()); ?>'>
</script>
```

In the same way, if you want to always refresh an image, just append it a random parameter:

```
<img src='/images/myImage.png?p=<?php print sha1(time()); ?>' />
```

You can do this with CSS files too.

Appending a random parameter to a resource will make the browser treat this resource as a new one, so it can't be loaded from cache.

Comment: Although this seemed like a good idea at first, I am not sure it is. I want the static content to only be refreshed on my development environment, not on production. If I do as you suggest, I will have to check everywhere what kind of environment is running, before I append the random parameter to the static content. Seems like a waste of resources to me.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Firefox add on called  "Web Developer" to temporarily disable the browser cache when I am working on web pages. You can toggle the cache on and off with it, amongst other things. I still think Beto Aveiga's plan is very interesting, I am thinking of a scheme to put it to use right now.

Answer (score 0):

GET requests are cached in the browser. Clear your browsers cache and set it to check for new files every time in the browser's settings.